# setters function inside constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to use a setter function inside of a constructor, which I've never done before. It's giving me the following error:

`[Error] no match for call to '(Laptop) (const char [5], const char [3], int, int)'`
**well do i need to write the setter function too ? i mean outside the constructor ? i mean like this**

```
void Laptop::setBrand(char a[])
   {   
        brand=a;}
```

I think the error is in the second constructor, that takes four arguments, but I'm not able to find it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class Laptop{
private:
        char brand[10];
        char processor[10];
        int ram;
        int hardDrive;
public:
        void setBrand(char Bra[]);
        void setProcessor(char Pro[]);
        void setRam(int Ram);
        void setHardDrive(int HDrive);


        char *getBrand();
        char *getProcessor();
        int  getRam();
        int getHardDrive();





        Laptop();
        Laptop(char [],char [],int ,int );                    
};

Laptop::Laptop(){

    cout<<"Default constructor called...\n";
    strcpy(brand,"None");
    strcpy(processor,"None);
    ram=0;
    hardDrive=0;
}
```

i think the error is in the constructor

```
 Laptop::Laptop(char Bra[],char Pro[],int Ram,int HDrive) 
   {
    cout<<"Parameterized constructor called...\n"; 
    setBrand(Bra );
    setProcessor(Pro );
    setRam(Ram);
    setHardDrive(HDrive);        
}
char *Laptop::getBrand()
{
    return brand;
}
char *Laptop::getProcessor()
{
  return processor;
}
int Laptop::getRam()
{
   return ram;
}
int Laptop::getHardDrive()
{
    return hardDrive;
}
int main()
{
    Laptop laptopObj1;
    Laptop laptopobj1("Dell","i5",4,500);
    cout<<"Brand :"<<laptopObj1.getBrand()<<"\n";

    cout<<"Processor :"<<laptopObj1.getProcessor()<<"\n";



    cout<<"Ram :"<<laptopObj1.getRam()<<"\n";



    cout<<"HardDrive :"<<laptopObj1.getHardDrive()<<"\n";

    cout<<"Brand :"<<laptopObj2.getBrand()<<"\n";

    cout<<"Processor :"<<laptopObj2.getProcessor()<<"\n";

    cout<<"Ram :"<<laptopObj2.getRam()<<"\n";

    cout<<"HardDrive :"<<laptopObj2.getHardDrive()<<"\n";

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error c2440: cannot convert const char\[4\] to char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134161/error-c2440-cannot-convert-const-char4-to-char)

Comment: replace all char arrays by std:string

Comment: Just wanna point out that in your default constructor Laptop::Laptop() your are declaring new variables and then they fall out of scope without you using them.

Comment: You are trying to pass `const` characters to a constructor that expects mutable characters.  While your error message is not the same as the proposed duplicate, the problem and solution are the same.

Comment: I think you should use std::string like @skeller said but you should also get a better understanding of how pointers and C strings work before using containers like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have alot of errors here..

```
Laptop laptopObj1,laptopObj2;
...
laptopObj2("Dell","i5", 4, 500);
```

You cant use the constructor twice. You used the constructor `Laptop()` in the first line for both of the object, and then tried to use the second constructor for `laptopObj2`.
You can change the second line to:

```
laptopObj2 = Laptop("Dell","i5", 4, 500);
```

Or even better to define it there:

```
Laptop laptopObj1;
....
Laptop laptopObj2("Dell","i5", 4, 500);
```

Another problem is inside your `Laptop()` constructor definition:

```
Laptop::Laptop(char Bra[],char Pro[],int Ram,int HDrive)
{
    .....
    setBrand(Bra []); // Remove the []
    setProcessor(Pro []); // Remove the []
    ....
}
```

And one more problem: You have no definitions for some functions of the class:

```
void setBrand(char Bra[]);
void setProcessor(char Pro[]);
void setRam(int Ram);
void setHardDrive(int HDrive);
void display();
```

EDIT:

One of the objects of c++ is `std::string` (`#include <string>`). You can use it instead of `char str[]`- just simpler way to declare strings in c++. For example, in your case:

```
/* Replace this: */
char brand[10];
char processor[10];

void setBrand(char Bra[]);
void setProcessor(char Pro[]);

char *getBrand();
char *getProcessor();

/* With this: */
string brand;
string processor;

void setBrand(const string &Bra);
void setProcessor(const string &Pro);

string getBrand();
string getProcessor();
```

Comment: Addendum: `char brand[10] = ": None \n";` in the `Laptop` constructor doesn't do anything useful. `char brand[10]` declares a new `brand` variable that is different from the private data member `char brand[10];`. This `brand` in the constructor only exists in the constructor. It is set to contain `": None \n"`. The member `brand` is left uninitialized.

Comment: @user4581301 you right. I forgot this thing when I created this post.

Comment: @KorelK sir do i have to write the definitions of setter function too ? i thought i dont need them if im using setter function inside the constructor
like 
           void Laptop::setBrand(char a[])
             {   
                  brand=a;}

Comment: @gintoki to use setter function inside (or outside) the constructor, you have to tell the compiler what the function does. In case that you don't write a definition to the called function, the compiler throw a definition missing error for this function.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing two  `const char*` as parameter, so you should change this :

`Laptop::Laptop(char Bra[],char Pro[],int Ram,int HDrive)`

to this:

`Laptop::Laptop(const char* ,const char* ,int Ram,int HDrive)`

Answer (score 0):

You really should use std::string rather than char[].

On the question of constructors, there is no need to call setters, as the following code demonstrates.  C++ has a shortcut for that capability. I have used std::string and fixed all typos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Laptop
{
private:
    string brand;
    string processor;
    int ram;
    int hardDrive;

public:
    void setBrand(string Bra);
    void setProcessor(string Pro);
    void setRam(int Ram);
    void setHardDrive(int HDrive);

    string getBrand();
    string getProcessor();
    int getRam();
    int getHardDrive();

    Laptop();
    Laptop(string, string, int, int);
};

Laptop::Laptop()
    : brand("None")
    , processor("None")
    , ram(0)
    , hardDrive(0)
{
    cout << "Default constructor called...\n";
}

Laptop::Laptop(string Bra, string Pro, int Ram, int HDrive)
    : brand(Bra)
    , processor(Pro)
    , ram(Ram)
    , hardDrive(HDrive)
{
    cout << "Parameterized constructor called...\n";
}

string Laptop::getBrand()
{
    return brand;
}

string Laptop::getProcessor()
{
    return processor;
}

int Laptop::getRam()
{
    return ram;
}

int Laptop::getHardDrive()
{
    return hardDrive;
}

int main()
{
    Laptop laptopObj1;
    Laptop laptopObj2("Dell", "i5", 4, 500);

    cout << "Brand :" << laptopObj1.getBrand() << "\n";

    cout << "Processor :" << laptopObj1.getProcessor() << "\n";

    cout << "Ram :" << laptopObj1.getRam() << "\n";

    cout << "HardDrive :" << laptopObj1.getHardDrive() << "\n";

    cout << "Brand :" << laptopObj2.getBrand() << "\n";

    cout << "Processor :" << laptopObj2.getProcessor() << "\n";

    cout << "Ram :" << laptopObj2.getRam() << "\n";

    cout << "HardDrive :" << laptopObj2.getHardDrive() << "\n";
}
```

Mike

Comment: "There is no need to call setters"- it's depends on how the definitions of the setters looks like. If you have some conditions there, you might want to pass the inputs through your setters...